# A variation of a Bekenstein's thought experiment

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, quantum-information

Consider a glass of water with mass $m$ and temperature $T_w$ released very close to the black hole horizon. The black hole being at temperature $T_{b} = \frac{1}{8\pi G M}$. Now, the final state is a black hole of mass $M+m$ and a therefore, a temperature $T'_b = \frac{1}{8\pi G(M+m)}$ which is clearly not equal to the expected temperature $a T_b+b T_w$ some linear combination. Now, does this also fall into the category of information loss as we have lost the information about the macroscopic properties of water? Or the black hole information loss paradox is strictly for quantum information like qubits etc.?

Comment: Bear in mind that falling even a short distance in the vicinity of a (stellar mass) black hole converts a *huge* amount of potential energy to kinetic energy. The  thermal energy of stuff falling into the BH is negligible in comparison. The BH will just eat it all up, and get a little colder.

Comment: @PM2Ring A good point. I changed it to something more accurate. What I meant is some linear combination. So, you are trying to say that macroscopic properties do not exactly count as information?

Comment: No , I'm definitely *not* saying that. All of those properties *do* count as information. And all that information gets lost, except for total energy (aka mass), electric charge, and angular momentum. So if you drop a litre of water into the BH it has the same effect as dropping a litre of antimatter water.

Comment: Your error is in using different frames of reference for different objects. You seem to consider the glass of water in its rest frame while considering the black hole in a remote frame. Most physical quantitles, such as energy, mass, temperature are frame dependent, so your formulas become incorrect when different frames are used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, information loss is both about classical and qubits.

Consider two glasses, one hot and one cold but with total mass tuned to be exactly the same. By the no hair theorem both generate indistinguishable end states when dropped into identical black holes: the initial thermal degrees of freedom do not matter.

Comment: This isn’t an example of the information loss, because the end state is never achieved. The no-hair theorem does not apply to a collapse in progress and the collapse never ends in any external frame. There is no information paradox without the Hawking radiation. A full evaporation of the black hole is required for the paradox to arise. No information is lost otherwise, ever.